# How to fix 'Unexpected token, expected ";"' in React Native/Expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to fetch Json data from https://api.myjson.com/bins/q47s3 and display it in a FlatList.

I'm using Expo. I started a new project using the react-native-tabs-template

And this is my code (HomeScreen.js):

```
export default function HomeScreen() {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dataSource: []
    }
  }

  renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <View>
      <Image source={{uri: item.image}} style={{width: 100, height: 100}}/>
      <View>
        <Text>{item.book_title}</Text>
        <Text>{item.author}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/q47s3'
    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: responseJson.book_array
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <View style={styles.searchBarHolder}>
          <Icon name='ios-search' style={{fontSize: 24}} />
          <TextInput placeholder='Search' style={{fontSize: 24, marginLeft: 15}} />
        </View>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.dataSource}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
  header: null,
};

Here's the error log:

```
Error: D:\Projects\React Native\fick\screens\HomeScreen.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (18:16)

  16 | import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
  17 | export default function HomeScreen() {
> 18 |   constructor() {
     |                 ^
  19 |     super()
  20 |     this.state = {
  21 |       dataSource: []
```

**UPDATE**

1. I replaced `export default function HomeScreen() {` with `export default class HomeScreen {`
2. I moved the last `return` method into the `render` method, so now the code looks like this:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dataSource: []
    }
  }

  renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <View style={styles.searchBarHolder}>
            <Icon name='ios-search' style={{fontSize: 24}} />
            <TextInput placeholder='Search' style={{fontSize: 24, marginLeft: 15}} />
          </View>
        </View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
      </View>

      <View>
      <Image source={{uri: item.image}} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />
      <View>
        <Text>{item.book_title}</Text>
        <Text>{item.author}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    )
  }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/q47s3'
    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: responseJson.book_array
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <View style={styles.searchBarHolder}>
            <Icon name='ios-search' style={{fontSize: 24}} />
            <TextInput placeholder='Search' style={{fontSize: 24, marginLeft: 15}} />
          </View>
        </View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
      </View>

      <View>
      <Image source={{uri: item.image}} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />
      <View>
        <Text>{item.book_title}</Text>
        <Text>{item.author}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    )
  }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/q47s3'
    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: responseJson.book_array
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

But now a new error shows, any idea what I did wrong, again?:

```
Error: D:\Projects\React Native\fick\screens\HomeScreen.js: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>? (42:6)

  40 |       </View>
  41 | 
> 42 |       <View>
     |       ^
  43 |       <Image source={{uri: item.image}} style={{width: 100, height: 100}}/>
  44 |       <View>
  45 |         <Text>{item.book_title}</Text>
```

Comment: Functions don't have methods. Did you mean to use a class?

Comment: so it should be `export default class HomeScreen {` instead?

Comment: Yes. And the very last `return` must be in a `render` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update code accordingly

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: []
    }
  }

componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/q47s3'
    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: responseJson.book_array
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }



  renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <View>
      <Image source={{uri: item.image}} style={{width: 100, height: 100}}/>
      <View>
        <Text>{item.book_title}</Text>
        <Text>{item.author}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    )
  }

  render(){
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <View style={styles.searchBarHolder}>
          <Icon name='ios-search' style={{fontSize: 24}} />
          <TextInput placeholder='Search' style={{fontSize: 24, marginLeft: 15}} />
        </View>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.dataSource}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
      />
    </View>
  );
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component{
  //your code
 render(){
   return()
 }
}
export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You used function and not a class.
2. Where is your render method? (Probably not this error but will create a new error because you don't have render method).
3. Add class to use constructor.

   ```
   export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
         constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           this.state = {
             dataSource: []
           }
         }
   ```